# Why does concatenating magic constants in classes cause fatal errors?

Tags: php

If I create a simple php class that looks like this:

```
<?php

class Test {
    public $dir = __DIR__.__FILE__;

    public function __construct() {
        echo $this->dir;
    }
}

new Test();
```

When the script runs, it fails with a fatal error:

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or `';'' in Test.php on line 4
```

However, if I remove the concatenation, for example `public $dir = __DIR__;`, the script works. Why would concatenating magic constants in this way cause a fatal error?

Comment: Quoting from the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php): `The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, or a function call.` Support for Constant expressions (such as concatenation) was added in PHP 5.6.0.

Comment: no parse error here: https://3v4l.org/aDRk5

Comment: So you are using a very old version of PHP i.e. php5.5 or lower

Comment: 5.5.38 or lower @RiggsFolly :-)

Comment: @Dagon Thanks for that, I had forgotten to load PHP5.5.38 into my testing system. Now I am current as far as obsolete code is concerned!